# Layout with decreasing height from one end to another in android (inclined on one side)

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is what I need to attain

[image]

The Application logo goes inside that blue background. Can I somehow tweak Linear or Relative Layout to attain that inclined bottom? Or is that any other solution to this, other than simply using an image itself?

Comment: why don't you put image background like this image , incase if you have only this color.

Comment: you can Make background with gradient color with start and endcolor so you get multiple color in background.

Answer (score 1):

No, Views in Android are all rectangular, and LinearLayout and RelativeLayout only deal in rectangular measurements.  You're going to have to do some special drawing or use a background image or something along those lines.